# Display listview using realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to pull data from a json file and list the school name in list form using an School adapter. I am new to realm.  Can anyone help me an example of how to do the adapter for realm so I can list the school names on the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private Realm realm;
private SchoolAdapter mAdapter;
String RealmPath;
static final String tag = "Realm Activity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        List<School> schools = null;
        try {
            schools = loadSchools();
            RealmPath =  realm.getPath();
            //Log.d( tag, String.valueOf(RealmPath));
            Log.d( tag, String.valueOf(schools));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();
    final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, R.id.schools_list, schools, true);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schools_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
}

public List<School> loadSchools() throws IOException{

    loadJsonFromStream();

    return realm.allObjects(School.class);

}

private void loadJsonFromStream() throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("school.json");

    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {
        realm.createAllFromJson(School.class, stream);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Remember to cancel the transaction if anything goes wrong.
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();


        }
    }

}
```

The School Adapter as followed:

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView school;
}

public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    School item = realmResults.get(position);
    viewHolder.school.setText(item.getSchoolName());
    return convertView;
}

public RealmResults<School> getRealmResults() {
    return realmResults;
}

}
```

The School class as followed:

```
public class School extends RealmObject {

@Required
private String SchoolID;
private String SchoolName;
private RealmList<Student> Students;


//getters..
//setters..
```

The main_activity xml as followed:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/schools_list"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: see this link https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm/tree/master/MyApplication/android-mvp-material-and-realm-master

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I just found out my code is right.  It just my json file that didn't have have the right names.